# Can't set properly jqueryUI datepicker when using array for numberOfMonth

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a problem with Jquery UI datepicker. When I try to set numberOfMonths options, the script fails with an error of "undefined is not a function". I'm using jquery ui 1.11.2. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var fechaDefecto = new Date('2014/01/01');
    var fechaFin = new Date('2014/08/31');
    var SelectedDates = {};
    SelectedDates[new Date('12/25/2014')] = new Date('12/25/2014');
    SelectedDates[new Date('12/12/2014')] = new Date('12/12/2014');
    SelectedDates[new Date('06/06/2014')] = new Date('06/06/2014');
    $('#cal').datepicker(
    {
            beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            var Highlight = SelectedDates[date];
            if (Highlight) {
                return [true, "Highlighted", Highlight];
            } else {
                return [true, '', ''];
            }
        }, 
        minDate : fechaDefecto,
        maxDate : fechaFin, 
        numberOfMonths: [2, 3]

    });
});
```

If I set numberOfMonths to a number and not an array, there is no problem, but the thing is I need to display a semester with two rows of 3 calendars for my application. 
I will really appreciate some help, please.

Another weird thing is that when I call the getter method for that option: `$('#cal').datepicker('option', 'numberOfMonths');` I get a correct output because it shows the array ([2, 3]).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the last stable version of Jquery UI wasn't working in my case, I switched to using  Jquery 1.8 and Jquery UI 1.9 and now it's working fine